# ListView onItemLongClick position

Tags: android, listview, long-press

I have a `ListView` inside a `Fragment`, and want to open a context menu on `LongClick`.

The thing is, the menu has to be opened from the click position, and

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, 
                                  final int position, final long id)
   { 
   }
```

does not have the `MotionEvent` or any indicator of the click position.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you not guess the position using the position of the View? by using view.getTop() etc

Comment: Why does it need to open right at the point of click?

Comment: You can also apply an onTouch listener to your view within your adapter.

Comment: Is a "Radial Menu" around the click location as seen in Pinterest, so the View location (getTop(), adapter/view onTouch(), etc) won't work for me.

Comment: "The thing is, the menu has to be opened from the click position" you must set click listener for each widget in the list row

Comment: Again, if you mean getView(){
...
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });

Is no good for me... View position is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListClickHandlerDelete implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 
    {
        String listPosition = list.get(position);
        return true;
    }
}
```